# DDL trigger not monitoring table trigger events

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following DDL trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE ddl_log (PostTime datetime, DB_User nvarchar(100), Event nvarchar(100), TSQL nvarchar(2000));
GO
CREATE TRIGGER log 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS 
AS
DECLARE @data XML;
SET @data = EVENTDATA();
INSERT ddl_log 
   (PostTime, DB_User, Event, TSQL) 
   VALUES 
   (GETDATE(), 
   CONVERT(nvarchar(100), CURRENT_USER), 
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'), 
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)') ) ;
GO
```

When I use SSMS (ie. UI) to enable/disable a table trigger, an event is inserted into the table.

However, when I use T-SQL as follows:

```
ENABLE trigger tr_mytable ON mytable
```

No event is inserted into the table.

Is this by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because GUI uses legacy syntax `ALTER TABLE DISABLE TRIGGER` that causes DDL trigger to fire, but the new syntax 'DISABLE TRIGGER' does not.

It's not catched by default trace too, some time ago you could vote this problem here: [Fire a DDL TRIGGER when the new syntax "DISABLE TRIGGER" is executed](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/509242/fire-a-ddl-trigger-when-the-new-syntax-disable-trigger-is-executed)

Now i's closed as Won't fix